# Add latitude and longitude to database with an angular form

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, typescript, forms

I'm trying to add a form to the database with some information, everything works except latitude and longitude. I tried a lot of things but I can't send the lat and the lng to the database
my code if below:

My Ts:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {ObservatoryService} from '../../../../@core/services/observatory.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngx-add-marker-modal',
  templateUrl: './add-marker-modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-marker-modal.component.scss'],
})
export class AddMarkerModalComponent implements OnInit {

  submitted = false;
  markerForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    public fb: FormBuilder,
    private router: Router,
    private obsService: ObservatoryService,
  ) {
    this.mainForm();
  }

  ngOnInit() { }

  // for the latitude and longitude validator but it doesn't work(pattern)
  // /^[-+]?([1-8]?\d(\.\d+)?|90(\.0+)?),\s*[-+]?(180(\.0+)?|((1[0-7]\d)|([1-9]?\d))(\.\d+)?)$/

  mainForm() {
    this.markerForm = this.fb.group({
      latitude: ['', [Validators.required]],
      longitude: ['', [Validators.required]],
      name: ['', [Validators.required]],
      pays: ['', [Validators.required]],
      image: ['', [Validators.required]],
      adresse: ['', [Validators.required]],
      desc: ['', [Validators.required]],
      contact: ['', [Validators.required]],
    });
  }

  get myForm() {
    return this.markerForm.controls;
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;
    if (!this.markerForm.valid) {
      return false;
    } else {
      this.obsService.addObserv(this.markerForm.value).subscribe(
        (res) => {
          console.log('Employee successfully created!');
        }, (error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
  }
}
```

My Html:

```
<nb-card>
  <nb-card-body>
    <form [formGroup]="markerForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputLatitude" class="label">Latitude</label>
            <input type="text"
                   nbInput
                   fullWidth
                   id="inputLatitude"
                   placeholder="Entrez un latidute"
                   formControlName="latitude">
            <!-- erreur -->
            <div class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="submitted && myForm.latitude.errors?.required">
              Une latitude est requise.
            </div>
<!--            &lt;!&ndash; erreur &ndash;&gt;-->
<!--            <div class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="submitted && myForm.latitude.errors?.pattern">-->
<!--              Une latitude est requise.-->
<!--            </div>-->
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputLongitude" class="label">Longitude</label>
            <input type="text"
                   nbInput
                   fullWidth
                   id="inputLongitude"
                   formControlName="longitude"
                   placeholder="Entrez un longitude">
            <!-- erreur -->
            <div class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="submitted && myForm.longitude.errors?.required">
              Une longitude est requise.
            </div>
<!--            &lt;!&ndash; erreur &ndash;&gt;-->
<!--            <div class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="submitted && myForm.longitude.errors?.pattern">-->
<!--              Une latitude est requise.-->
<!--            </div>-->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputName" class="label">Nom</label>
            <input type="email"
                   nbInput fullWidth
                   id="inputName"
                   formControlName="name"
                   placeholder="Entrez un nom">
            <!-- erreur -->
            <div class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="submitted && myForm.name.errors?.required">
              Le nom est requis.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputPays" class="label">Entrez un pays</label>
              <input type="text"
                     nbInput
                     fullWidth
                     id="inputPays"
                     formControlName="pays"
                     placeholder="Entrez un longitude">
              <!-- erreur -->
              <div class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="submitted && myForm.pays.errors?.required">
                Le pays est requis.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputImage" class="label">Image(entrez un lien ou une adresse d'image)</label>
                <input type="text"
                       nbInput
                       fullWidth
                       id="inputImage"
                       formControlName="image"
                       placeholder="Entrez une image">
                <!-- erreur -->
                <div class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="submitted && myForm.image.errors?.required">
                  Une image est requise.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="inputAdresse" class="label">Adresse</label>
                  <input type="text"
                         nbInput
                         fullWidth
                         id="inputAdresse"
                         formControlName="adresse"
                         placeholder="Entrez une adresse">
                  <!-- erreur -->
                  <div class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="submitted && myForm.adresse.errors?.required">
                    Une adresse est requise.
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputContact" class="label">Contact</label>
                    <input type="text"
                           nbInput
                           fullWidth
                           id="inputContact"
                           formControlName="contact"
                           placeholder="Entrez un longitude">
                    <!-- erreur -->
                    <div class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="submitted && myForm.contact.errors?.required">
                      Un contact est requis.
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="inputDesc" class="label">Description</label>
                      <textarea type="text"
                                nbInput
                                fullWidth
                                id="inputDesc"
                                formControlName="desc"
                                placeholder="Entrez une description"></textarea>
                      <!-- erreur -->
                      <div class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="submitted && myForm.desc.errors?.required">
                        Une description est requise.
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button status="success" type="submit" nbButton>Ajouter</button>
                  </div>
    </form>
  </nb-card-body>
</nb-card>
```

res console:

[image]

res database: [image]

My form is sent to the database, but without the latitude and longitude and I don't understand why, someone could help me please.
ps: the API model works correctly when I do a getAll of the marker to display them on my map (marker blue on the image)

Comment: Have you checked the data before posting to your server? Have you checked what data your server recieves? Have you checked what data you are saving to the database?

Comment: yes I receive in base all the data except the latitude and the longitude

Comment: What do you mean by *I receive in base* ?? It would be quite useful if you answered all of my questions.

Comment: I receive the data of my form in database apart from the latitude and the longitude because the model expects a type number but when the form submit it sends the latitude and the longitude in the form of string and I do not understand why.
And yes I checked the res in the console and in the database

Comment: ok i found the problem it was just the variable names which were not correct in my model : /
thank you for your help, have a nice day